# Specify targets in externalNativeBuild of the build.gradle file-> No signature of method

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake, java-native-interface

1. Start a new native c++ project in android studio 4.1.1.
2. Go to `build.gradle` of the module
3. Add a `targets` line:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
            targets "native-lib"  // New line
        }
    }
```

Somehow I get an error when I click the green play button (Run 'app'):

```
Build file '<project folder>/app/build.gradle' line: 5
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_bcdq4hni531na6stswx8a7txx.android() is 
applicable for argument types: (build_bcdq4hni531na6stswx8a7txx$_run_closure1) 
values: [build_bcdq4hni531na6stswx8a7txx$_run_closure1@41fd5f78]
```

What is going on?

The `targets` property is documented at: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds

The answer to this question also use the `targets` property.
[Disabling a CMake target when building Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007783/disabling-a-cmake-target-when-building-android-app)

I can't even pass an argument to CMake by adding `arguments "-DOPTION=1"` to `build.gradle`!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe the "targets" and other options are to be placed in android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild (instead of android.externalNativeBuild).

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        :
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "native-lib" // New line here!
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
            // targets "native-lib"  // Not here!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent a whole day on this. Thanks a lot!