# How to detect cpu architecture of Android via cmake

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, native

Brief:
Does anyone know if it possible to configure Cmake to add sub_directory base on Android ABIs (x86,arm64-v8a)?
Something likes:

```
if (android_x64)
 add_subdirectory(${distribution_DIR}/android_x64)
elseif(android_arm64)
 add_subdirectory(${distribution_DIR}/android_arm64)
endif()
```

More Detail:
My scenario is that for a directory structure such as:

```
AndroidStudioProject
-CMakeLists.txt
-third_party
    -android_x64
      CMakeListsA.txt
    -android_arm64
      CMakeListsB.txt
```

**The CMakeLists.txt (Root Project) looks like this:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# configure import libs
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/out)


add_subdirectory(${distribution_DIR}/android_x64})
add_subdirectory(${distribution_DIR}/android_arm64)
```

**CMakeListA.txt:**

```
# Generated by gn_to_cmake.py.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(VERSION 3.7)

file(WRITE "/third_party//out/android_x64/empty.cpp")

#//:default
set("target" "default")
set("${target}__cxx_srcs" "/third_party/out/android_x64/empty.cpp")
add_custom_target("${target}" SOURCES ${${target}__cxx_srcs})
add_dependencies("${target}"
  "build__chip__java__tests_java_build_test"
  "src__app"
  "src__app__server")
```

**CMakeListB.txt:**

```
# Generated by gn_to_cmake.py.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(VERSION 3.7)

file(WRITE "/third_party//out/android_arm64/empty.cpp")

#//:default
set("target" "default")
set("${target}__cxx_srcs" "/third_party/out/android_arm64/empty.cpp")
add_custom_target("${target}" SOURCES ${${target}__cxx_srcs})
add_dependencies("${target}"
  "build__chip__java__tests_java_build_test"
  "src__app"
  "src__app__server")
```

**externalNativeBuild in Gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "default"
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.10.2'
             path '../CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping that someone with more experience with native development on Android could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "to call a custom_target"? If you want to perform actions, binded to that custom target, before actions in the new custom target, then adjust dependencies between targets (`add_dependencies`). Please, update your question post with some **examples** of the code which you have and which you want to achieve.

Comment: Sr for my bad English. I mean build a cmake target "default" which is defined in either CMakeListsA or CMakeListsB via build.gradle(app)

Comment: In CMake custom targets are **global**. So if top-level `CMakeLists.txt` includes `CMakeListsA.txt`, which in turn defines a target `Foo`, then you could build that target as usual, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829814/3440745).

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. My top-level CMakeLists.txt include both of CMakeListA.txt and CMakeListB.txt. And a target `Foo` is defind in both of them

Comment: "a target Foo is defined in both of them" - CMake doesn't normally allow that. Do you set variable [ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS.html) for allow duplicate target names?

Comment: Yes, I try to `set(ALLOW_DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TARGETS TRUE)`. It stills get an error: `..another target with
the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
created in source directory`

Comment: What you got is a **configuration** error, which definitely prepends "**build** a cmake target" as you describe in the question post. Please, update you question post to contain **complete code** (in form of [mcve]) and to contain a **complete error message**.

Comment: I assume you're trying to add exactly one of those. you may be able to do something like `add_subdirectory("${distribution_DIR}/android_${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" third_party_build)`, but the directory names may not match exactly with the names of the directories though...

Comment: My problem is how to detect Android ABIs (x86,arm) to `add_subdirectory` suitable via CmakeList.txt. Something likes:
`if (android_x64)
add_subdirectory(android_x64)`